# Why must the features be local for a Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

Assume we have an Hidden Markov Model:

```
 h1 -> h2 -> h3 -> h4
 |     |     |     |
 v     v     v     v 
 x1   x2    x3     x4
```

with Markov Property (can be read from the graph), e.g.

$p(h_3 | h_1, h_2, x_{1:4}) = p(h_3 | h_2, x_{1:4})$

In the literature (e.g. K. Murphy) you find that an HMM must have local features (only an edge 
from $h_2$ to $x_2$): "since it's hard to define a generative model for the whole stream of observations ${\bf x} = {\bf x}_{1:T}$".

What does that mean?

Can I argue like this:

If there were edges from the $h_i$ to all $x_j$ then on each $x_j$ there is a multiple V-structure. Because the $x_j$ are observed the V-structures are active and there are active paths from each $h_i$ to the other $h_k$. 
So the Markov property is lost.

Is this argumentation correct? What's the relation to "it's hard to define a generative model ..."?

Thanks for your help.

Note: In the original post was a mistake. I corrected the argumentation.

Comment: The emission probabilities become much more complicated: instead of $p(x_i | h_i)$ we would have the $p(x_i | h_1, h_2, ..., h_T)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMM's are the simplest form of Dynamic Bayesian Networks. Have a look at this [tutorial paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ijprai.pdf) which starts by defining HMM's and then talks about Bayesian Networks before finally introducing Dynamic Bayesian Networks.

It is indeed hard to define a generative model since you need to model the joint probability distribution from which (you would hypothesize) your dataset was drawn. Since calculating the joint probability distribution is not computationally possible in most cases, we make independence assumptions. In a temporal setting, as you point out, one of the simplest assumptions to make is the Markov condition.

There are Dynamic BN's that make less simplifying assumptions compared to HMM's but then they are much more difficult to fit computationally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. It maybe hairspiltting, but the __definition__ and the data generating process is quite clear for a general BN, e.g. I can sample from the network quite easy if I have the parameters. Learning and inference would be more complicated (without the Markov property).